# Redirect outside the current domain using javascript

Tags: javascript, xss

I want to redirect to another website outside of my domain, such as this:

```
<img src="http://url.to.file.which/not.exist" onerror=window.open("www.google.com","xss",'height=500,width=500');>
```

I put the above code into a simple html file. However, it keeps appending the file path before "www.google.com" when the pop up show up. Is there a way to remove?

Comment: It's because you provided a *relative* URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the **protocol** -  `http(s)://` -  before the domain

```
<img src="http://url.to.file.which/not.exist" onerror=window.open("https://www.google.com","xss",'height=500,width=500');>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the full URL: `window.open("http://www.google.com"...`

Answer (score 2):

To use an absolute url you need to specify the protocol. In your case you want `http://`.

So just change `www.google.com` to `http://www.google.com`